# converting a 2d dictionary to a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a huge dictionary something like this:

```
d[id1][id2] = value
```

example:

```
books["auth1"]["humor"] = 20
books["auth1"]["action"] = 30
books["auth2"]["comedy"] = 20
```

and so on..

Each of the "auth" keys can have any set of "genres" associated wtih them. The value for a keyed item is the number of books they wrote.

Now what I want is to convert it in a form of matrix...something like:

```
                    "humor"       "action"        "comedy"
      "auth1"         20            30               0
      "auth2"          0            0                20
```

How do i do this?
Thanks

Comment: first iterating thru the dictionary and then finding the number of rows and columns.. after that as i am iterating converting each entry as a defined vector.. and then in another iteration thru id1.. associating it with their vectors

Comment: Do you just want it printed out like that? Why does it need to go into a numpy matrix

Comment: @PaulSeeb: no no.. actually I want to later to perform svd of this matrix..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to turn a dict into a list of lists and/or a numpy array:

```
np.array([[books[author][genre] for genre in sorted(books[author])] for author in sorted(books)])
```

*EDIT*

Apparently you have an irregular number of keys in each sub-dictionary. Make a list of all the genres:

```
genres = ['humor', 'action', 'comedy']
```

And then iterate over the dictionaries in the normal manner:

```
list_of_lists = []
for author_name, author in sorted(books.items()):
    titles = []
    for genre in genres:
        try:
            titles.append(author[genre])
        except KeyError:
            titles.append(0)
    list_of_lists.append(titles)

books_array = numpy.array(list_of_lists)
```

Basically I'm attempting to append a value from each key in `genres` to a list. If the key is not there, it throws an error. I catch the error, and append a 0 to the list instead.

Comment: Hi, this gives me : array([[20, 30], [50]], dtype=object)

but what i was expecting was [[20, 30, 0],[0,0,50]]

Comment: @Fraz: ah, so you have an irregular number of keys for each author dict. Let me edit.

Answer (score 27):

[pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) do this very well:

```
books = {}
books["auth1"] = {}
books["auth2"] = {}
books["auth1"]["humor"] = 20
books["auth1"]["action"] = 30
books["auth2"]["comedy"] = 20

from pandas import *

df = DataFrame(books).T.fillna(0)
```

The output is:

```
       action  comedy  humor
auth1      30       0     20
auth2       0      20      0
```

Comment: @HYRY Can a pandas DataFrame be used as input for matplotlib.pcolor to create a heat map? Or does one have to convert to a numpy array first?

Comment: In case of variable-length dictionary values, use `DataFrame.from_dict(books, orient='index').fillna(0)` instead to prevent `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0):

In 2018, I think that Pandas 0.22 supports this [out of the box](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html).
Specifically, please check the `from_dict` class method of `DataFrame`.

```
books = {}
books["auth1"] = {}
books["auth2"] = {}
books["auth1"]["humor"] = 20
books["auth1"]["action"] = 30
books["auth2"]["comedy"] = 20

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(books, orient='columns', dtype=None)
```