# Python Pandas - "1D" file to 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pandas, symmetric

I saw [an answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623592/converting-a-2d-dictionary-to-a-numpy-matrix) on converting a nested "2D" dictionary to a Pandas DataFrame. That would be a solution to my problem, but then I was wondering, whether I can the skip the intermediate step of generating a nested dictionary. Let's say my ***input*** `input.txt` looks like this:

```
A B 1
A C 2
B C 3
```

Can I convert that to the following symmetric matrix with either Pandas or Numpy without having to generate an intermediate nested dictionary?

```
  A B C
A 0 1 2
B 1 0 3
C 2 3 0
```

The nested dictionary that I want to avoid creating would be:

```
d = {'A':{'B':1,'C':2},'B':{'C':3}}
```

I tried this after reading the IO Tools documentation on ["Reading an index with a MultiIndex"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#reading-an-index-with-a-multiindex):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input.txt', sep=' ', index_col=[0,1], header=None)
```

But I don't get a 2D heat map, when I do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.pcolor(df)
plt.imshow()
```

Comment: Instead of explaining the accepted answer in your question, you might edit or suggest an edit to DSM's answer, putting the explanation in the answer itself

Comment: Will do that straight away @tim-castelijns. Thanks for teaching me the procedure.

Comment: No worries. It just better fits the Q&A format

Comment: Where? Also an edit doesn't need to say `EDIT:`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure whether this is all that much more efficient, but you could [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and then add the frame to its transpose, something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv("input.txt", header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
df = df.pivot(0,1,2)
df.add(df.T, fill_value=0).fillna(0)

   A  B  C
A  0  1  2
B  1  0  3
C  2  3  0
```

---

Here is the documentation on [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) and [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). Here is what is going on. The first line `df = pd.read_csv("input.txt", header=None, delim_whitespace=True)` returns:

```
   0  1  2
0  A  B  1
1  A  C  2
2  B  C  3
```

The second line `df = df.pivot(0,1,2)` then returns:

```
1   B   C
0           
A   1   2
B NaN   3
```

The magic numbers `0`, `1` and `2` are `index`, `columns` and `values`. `index=0` is the column name to use to make the index of the new frame. `index` is just pandas lingo for a row name. `columns=1` is the column name to use to make the columns of the new frame. And `values=2` is just the column name to use for making the values of the new frame.

The third line `df.add(df.T, fill_value=0).fillna(0)` just adds the transpose to convert the triangular matrix to a symmetric matrix. It returns:

```
   A  B  C
A  0  1  2
B  1  0  3
C  2  3  0
```

Comment: thank you for being the first person to show me, why I should perhaps bother learning pandas. Sorry for not voting up your answer immediately, but I had to read the documentation first to understand the `df.pivot(0,1,2)` part of your answer.

Comment: It's not efficient, but it's only 3 lines of code, which is essential to me, since this is for a practical I'm doing for a course in Africa with participants that have little programming experience. Super grateful. Thank you.