# Heatmap of a dictionary of dictionaries with numerical values

Tags: python, matrix, heatmap

I am trying to make a heatmap of a probability matrix that looks somehow like this (with seaborn): [image: probability matrix]

```
heat_map = sb.heatmap(prob_matrix, xticklabels=b, yticklabels=b)
```

Now I tried to do this with my matrix but the function doesn't work with the way my matrix is built up. Can anyone help me writing a new function for a heatmap with my matrix? Or help me convert my matrix so I can use the function above?

My matrix looks like this, it is 20x20 but I will give a smaller version:

```
{'A': {'A': 0.25, 'C': 0.5, 'D': 0.25}, 'C': {'A': 0.33, 'C': 0.33, 'D': 0.33}, 'D': {'A': 0.75, 'C': 0.25, 'D': 0}}
```

Comment: As per https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html you need to convert your matrix to something ndarray-like. I would recommend iterating over your existing matrix to make a ndarray matrix.

Comment: @PiRocks , yes I realised that for this function you need an array. Is there a way I can convert my matrix to an array?

Comment: To do the conversion of your dict of dicts, try something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623592/converting-a-2d-dictionary-to-a-numpy-matrix

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your dict in the required format

```
data = [np.array(list(d.values())) for d in probs.values()]
>>> data
[array([ 0.25,  0.5 ,  0.25]), array([ 0.33,  0.33,  0.33]), array([ 0.75,  0.25,  0.  ])]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pandas can help converting your data in a form that seaborn can work with:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb

data = {'A': {'A': 0.25, 'C': 0.5, 'D': 0.25}, 
        'C': {'A': 0.33, 'C': 0.33, 'D': 0.33}, 
        'D': {'A': 0.75, 'C': 0.25, 'D': 0}}

prob_matrix = pd.DataFrame(data).T.fillna(0)
sb.heatmap(prob_matrix)
```

This will plot your matrix with the labels of the original dictionary.